# A nice generating set for the symmetric power of an algebra

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, symmetric-algebras, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

I'm looking for a reference for the following fact.

Suppose $A$ is a finitely generated associative commutative unital algebra over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.  Let $S^n(A)$ be the $n$-th symmetric power of $A$.  That is, $S^n(A)$ is the subalgebra of $A^{\otimes n}$ fixed by the natural action of $S_n$ on this tensor product by permuting the factors.  I would like to know a reference for the fact that $S^n(A)$ is generated by elements of the form

$(a \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots \otimes 1) + (1 \otimes a \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots \otimes 1) + \cdots + (1 \otimes \cdots \otimes 1 \otimes a)$

for $a$ in $A$.

Note that if $A = \mathbb{C}[t]$, then $S^n(A)$ is the ring of symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables and then the result follows from the fact that the power sum polynomials generate this ring.

I call the above a "fact" since I've seen it used in papers (without proof -- and I've contacted the authors and they don't know of a reference) and a colleague of mine says he could write out a proof.  However, I can't help but think that there must be a reference for this in some text.  But I'm unable to find one...

Alternatively, if someone knows of a very short proof, that would be the next best thing to a reference.  I want to use this fact in a paper I'm writing and I'd like to avoid having to digress from the main thread of the exposition by including a long proof of this fact.

Comment: Pedantic remark: Your definition of $S^n(A)$ does not coincide with the usual definition of the symmetric algebra when $k$ has positive characteristic. But this definition is obviously useful here because it inherits $S^n(A)$ with an algebra structure.

Comment: see my comment to MO 122287.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks.  I meant to say that the field has characteristic zero.  I've updated the question to include this assumption.

Comment: It's Lemma 4.56 (ii) in Etingof's "Introduction to representation theory" ( http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf ), though the proof of part (i) given there is not the easiest and relies on representation theory (unsurprisingly for a representation theory text). I believe this is one of those facts better proven than cited away for the sake of reader...

Comment: @darij: Thanks.  Since the paper I'm writing is a representation theory paper, this is quite a good reference for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your algebra is finitely generated, you only really need this result in the case when $A=\mathbb{C}[t_1,\ldots,t_n]$.

It seems that this result first appeared in

F. Junker, *Über symmetrische Funktionen von mehreren Reihen von Veränderlichen*, Math. Ann. 43 (1893), 225-270

(see [here](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0043&DMDID=DMDLOG_0024) for a scanned version of it).

A much more modern reference (from which I know about Junker's paper) is

J. Dalbec, *Multisymmetric functions*, Beiträge zur Algebra und Geometrie, Vol. 40 (1999), No. 1, pp. 27-51.

(see [here](http://www.emis.de/journals/BAG/vol.40/no.1/3.html) for an electronic version).

**Edit:** as Abdelmalek Abdesselam suggests, this result goes back to

L. Schläfli, *Über die Resultante eines Systemes mehrerer algebraischer Gleichungen Ein Beitrag zur Theorie der Elimination.* (A. d. IV Bd. der Denkschriften der math.-naturw. Classe der kais. Acad. d. Wiss. bes. abgedruckt), Wien 1852

(see [here](http://www.bsb-muenchen-digital.de/~web/web1094/bsb10942369/images/index.html?digID=bsb10942369&pimage=00001&v=pdf&nav=0&l=de) for a scanned version).

Comment: it's even older than that, it is in the 1852 paper by Schlafli on resultants.

Comment: Thanks! My command of German is not enough to conclude that Schlafli's paper contains a proof. I shall add a reference in the body of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Vladmir and Abdelmalek.  Of course, I think one would need to include the proof that if the result is true for A then it is true for any homomorphic image of A, in order to deduce the result for finitely generated algebras.  Luckily that isn't so hard (although not immediately obvious, I think).